# PSQL command is prompting password input on Mac OS X

Tags: postgresql

I have PostgreSQL (version 10.4) installed on my Mac computer. When I execute the PSQL command in the Mac terminal, a passcode input prompts. During the installation, I do not recall setting up a passcode to use this command. I have tried running this command as a root and default user (daniellee) to no avail. How do I find out what the passcode is? Or, at best, remove the password prompt?

Here's the setting I have for PostgreSQL in my computer: [image]

Comment: What did you try so far, have you done any research? First result search engine gave me was https://serverfault.com/questions/110154/whats-the-default-superuser-username-password-for-postgres-after-a-new-install

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue was. Essentially, I was trying to access psql database with a non-existing user, which was "daniellee," when I should be authenticating using "postgres" user. Running the following command helped

`psql -U postgres.`

The password is the same one entered during installation of the database.